# How to register interop .net asssembly per user Without Administrator Privileges using InstallShield

Tags: c#, winforms, admin, installshield, privileges

I am working on a task not to prompt a normal user a popup(UAC) for approval to install windows Addin application while registering a .net assembly during installation using instalshield. On windows xp, its working fine but during installation on vista and windows 7, a popup comes up for approval. As per the requirement, it shouldnt come. Is there any way to bypass this pop up on vista and windows 7 if UAC is on and registered the assembly per user without administrator privileges?

Kindly help?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have to register those assemblies? I thought they could just go into the bin folder.

Comment: we have one project(class library) that is used to export charts from the web to ms word,excel,powerpoint. we need to register that project (project.dll) dll to the windows registry. we are doing this using installshield.

Comment: You cannot tinker with the user's registry without going through the UAC prompt.  This prompt was not designed to stop you from doing what you want to do, it is only there to make the user aware that you are making permanent changes to her machine configuration.  There is no good reason to hide that fact unless the intent is malicious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, COM can be registered per-user or per-machine as HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a view derived from both HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.   If you run  regasm /regfile:foo.dll you can generate a regfile and then change all the references in the key names to make it local to the current user.

In the .reg file that gets generated, all the reg key additions will be to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. You need to replace these with "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes".

Also if you need the COM registration to work with 32 bit applications and you're running x64, then for additions to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID, you'll need to insert "\Wow6432Node" before the CLSID token like.

To be clear, additions to "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID" become "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID". To make it work on x86 you only need to make this change for CLSID entries.

Also, in certain situations, you can consider making use of Registration Free COM Interop by creating a manifest file for the EXE that consumes the COM server to make the ProgID/ClassID's available to the EXE without actually writing the registration information to the registry.

Comment: I have generated the reg file using regasm of that dll. When and how i need to change the references in the key names. is it during installation? Plz provide the example related to Registration Free COM?

Comment: Anywhere it says [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE] in the .reg file change it to say [KEY_CURRENT_USER].  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: is there any automated way to change the key names during installation of the product?

Comment: What InstallShield project type are you?  You don't need to do this during the installation, it's a one time step during the authoring.  Run regasm /regfile on your DLL to create the regfile.  Then edit it in notepad to change the references to HKCU.  Then import the reg file into your installshield project and change the references to the dll's to use MSI [#foo] file keys.  Finally turn off .NET COM Interop on the component so InstallShield doesn't run regasm during the build.

Comment: BTW, I've answered this question.  To implement the solution you'll have to understand how InstallShield works which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: we are using basic msi project.

Comment: I have import the reg file and turned off the .net COM interop. but how to change the refernces to the dlls to use MSI [#foo] file keys??

Comment: In MSI [FOO] refers to the property FOO.  [#FOO] refers to a file in the File table with an File Id of FOO.  In your registry entries if you see something like ...\foo.dll you have to replace it with [#FOO].   Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake among developers which are not familiar with elevation and user privileges.

The assembly you are installing is registered per-machine. This is why it requires elevation for its registration process. It's also elevated on XP, but you don't see if because its automatic. If you would run the installation under a normal user account, it would fail because of insufficient privileges.

Since this assembly was designed to be registered per-machine, why are you trying to change its behavior? It's like trying to modify Windows to support your application. You adapt to the environment, not the other way around.

So the correct solution would be to use a per-machine installer. This way your installation process will be installed for all users and will always require Administrator privileges.

Per-user installations are designed for products which use only per-user locations. If you are installing resources in a per-machine location, then you should use a per-machine installation.

Comment: if we use per-machine installation, then how to avoid the approval popup of UAC?

Comment: You don't. Per-machine installations need elevation.