# Returning string from C# library function crashes VBA calling application

Tags: c#, vba, outlook

I've built an unmanaged C# library to consume a web service (tested, working). The web service takes a given project ID and returns the internal ID in the project management system. This is useful as I can then deep-link into projects in VBA, applications, etc.

I wanted to use this library in VBA using a Declare statement (I can't register it as I won't have access to the registry on client machines). This *somewhat* works. I used the RGiesecke.DllExport library to export functions instead of the class, and for the function that returns the internal ID (as an integer), this works great. What I am trying to do, however, is make a function that returns the fully built URL to VBA (or whatever the caller is). This would make it much more user friendly to use the library without having to muck with string concatenation and manipulation after getting an internal ID. This is what's causing trouble - the string comes back (I see it in the debug console), and then Outlook just hangs - no error, the screen will just go white and be non-responsive.

To test, I replaced the GetLink function with a simple C# function with the same name & prototype that returns "Test" and the same thing happens, so I don't think I'm overflowing the string or anything. I then made the same function return an int and returned 0, which worked fine. Therefore, it's definitely something with returning a string. I suspect it's something in how the function is being called, or how VBA is trying to clean up the stack (maybe string sizes are are different in C# and VBA and it's going into protected mem?), but I'm really not sure. Per some other threads, I also tried declaring the function in VBA as returning an Object, and had the same result.

Code for C# lib and VBA sub follows.

**Here's the C# library:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

public class ClarityWebService 
{
    [DllExport("GetInternalID", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int GetInternalID(string projectID)
    {
        const String USERNAME = "the_username";
        const String PASSWORD = "the_password";
        int internalID;
        projectID = projectID.Trim()

        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("<REST URL>/" + projectID);
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Boolean responseSuccess = true;

        request.Method = "GET";    
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

        // ACTUALLY HIT THE WEB SERVICE AND GET THE INTERNAL ID
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            responseSuccess = false;
        }

        /* 
        * Only return the Internal ID on success. If the try failed,
        * there might be a network problem or an invalid Clarity ID was given, so return -1
        */
        Stream responseDataStream;
        String responseFromServer = "-1";

        if (responseSuccess)
        {
            // Get response as stream
            responseDataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Read the stream
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseDataStream);

            // Parse through response
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            bool resultofConv = Int32.TryParse(responseFromServer, out internalID);

            // The server should have sent an internal ID, which is an integer
            // If something else is returned, something is wrong
            if (resultofConv != true)
                internalID = -1;

            // Cleanup
            reader.Close();
            responseDataStream.Close();
            response.Close();            
        }
        else
        {
            internalID = -1;
        }

        return internalID;
    }

    [DllExport("GetLink", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static string GetLink(string projectID, string LinkType = "Main")
    {
        projectID = projectID.Trim();
        int intId = GetInternalID(projectID);
        string strIntId = intId.ToString();

        if (intId != -1)
            return BuildCorrectLink(strIntId,LinkType);
        else
            return "Error getting internal id for project " + projectID + " - make sure project is valid";
    }

    private static string BuildCorrectLink(string internalId, string LinkType = "Main")
    {
        // Generic deep links to various parts of a project
        const string mainLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";
        const string statusReportLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>;
        const string dashboardLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";
        const string auditLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";
        const string hierarchyLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";
        const string tasksLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";
        const string ganttLink = "<URL>&id=<INTERNAL ID>";

        // Replace the <INTERNAL ID> in the generic link with the actual Internal ID and return it
        switch (LinkType.Trim())
        {
            // If LinkType = "Main" or is blank
            case "Main" : case "":
                return mainLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Status Report":
                return statusReportLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Dashboard":
                return dashboardLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Audit":
                return auditLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Hierarchy":
                return hierarchyLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Tasks":
                return tasksLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            case "Gantt":
                return ganttLink.Replace("<INTERNAL ID>", internalId);
                break;
            default:
                return "Error - unknown subpage requested";
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is the VBA code:**

```
Option Explicit
' DEBUG function declarations
Declare Function GetInternalID Lib "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ClarityWebService\ClarityWebService\bin\Debug\ClarityWebService.dll" (ByVal ProjectID As String) As Long
Declare Function GetLink Lib "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ClarityWebService\ClarityWebService\bin\Debug\ClarityWebService.dll" (ByVal ProjectID As String, Optional ByVal LinkType As String) As String

' Shared drive function declarations
'Declare Function GetInternalID Lib "Shared Network Drive\ClarityWebService.dll" (ByVal ProjectID As String) As Long
'Declare Function GetLink Lib "Shared Network Drive\ClarityWebService.dll" (ByVal ProjectID As String, Optional ByVal LinkType As String) As String


Sub TestClarityWebService()        
    ' The line below works (I see a link in the debug console),
    ' but Outlook crashes right after
    Debug.Print (GetLink("ID_of_Project1", "Main"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to offer an alternative, in case you didn't know: [You don't need admin permissions to register an interop .net assembly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594280/how-to-register-interop-net-asssembly-per-user-without-administrator-privileges) This might allow you to call your methods without all that unmanaged magic.

Comment: @Heinzi: thank you for that link. It seems interesting and I'll keep that option in mind, but I don't think it will fit my present needs. My current goal is to be able to distribute Outlook VBA modules & Excel .xlm files which reference the .dll on a shared drive, or to distribute the code and library together. I'm not presently working on creating a full-fledged application that would be installed via InstallShield.